# Erro no codigo em PHP

Tags: php

Estou a fazer um exercicio da escola e dá-me um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario de Inscriçao</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Formulario para Inscriçao de Competidores</p>
<form action="script.php" method="get">
<p>Seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /></p>
<p>Sua idade: <input type="text" name="idade" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Enviar dados do competidor"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
$categorias = [];
$categorias[]='Infantil';
$categorias[]='Adolescente';
$categorias[]='Adulto';
$categorias[]='Idoso';


$nome=$_GET['nome'];
$idade=$_GET['idade'];


if($idade >= 6 && $idade <= 12)
{
    for($i = 0;$i<=count($categorias);$i++)
    {
        if($categorias[$i]=='Infantil')
            echo 'O nadador '. $nome .'compete na categoria Infantil'; 
    }
}
else if($idade>=13 && $idade<=18)
{
    for($i = 0;$i<=count($categorias);$i++)
    {
        if($categorias[$i] == 'Adolescente')
            echo "O nadador ".$nome."compete na categoria Adolescente"; 
    }
}
else
{
    for($i = 0;$i<=count($categorias);$i++)
    {
        if($categorias[$i] == 'Adulto')
            echo 'O nadador '. $nome .'compete na categoria Adulto'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: As perguntas do site com código tem que conter um [mcve], de forma a servirem de referência para um público amplo, e o problema ser identificado até por leigos, e não o código original. Fazendo assim, pessoas com o mesmo problema encontrarão solução nas respostas, que é o objetivo aqui. Ainda, mero debug de código não atende nosso objetivo. Mais detalhes em [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, no array ele tem os elementos 0, 1, 2, 3, no for com <=, ele estava acessando 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, quando se esta começando e interessante colocar um echo e ir acompanhando as chaves.

Esse código funciona:

```
<?php
    $categorias = [];
    $categorias[]='Infantil';
    $categorias[]='Adolescente';
    $categorias[]='Adulto';
    $categorias[]='Idoso';

    if($idade >= 6 && $idade <= 12)
    {
        for($i = 0;$i<count($categorias);$i++)
        {
            if($categorias[$i]=='Infantil')
                echo 'O nadador '. $nome .'compete na categoria Infantil'; 
        }
    }
    else if($idade>=13 && $idade<=18)
    {
        for($i = 0;$i<count($categorias);$i++)
        {
            if($categorias[$i] == 'Adolescente')
                echo "O nadador ".$nome."compete na categoria Adolescente"; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0;$i<count($categorias);$i++)
        {
            if($categorias[$i] == 'Adulto')
                echo 'O nadador '. $nome .'compete na categoria Adulto'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

Recomendo dar uma estudada no código abaixo:

```
<?php
    $categorias = array();
    array_push($categorias, "Infantil", "Adolescente", "Adulto", "Idoso");

    function functionName($nome, $categoria, $categorias) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($categorias); $i++) {
            if ($categorias[$i] == $categoria){ 
                echo 'O nadador ' . $nome . ' compete na categoria ' . $categoria;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['nome']) && isset($_GET['idade'])){
        $nome = htmlspecialchars($_GET['nome']);
        $idade = htmlspecialchars($_GET['idade']);

        if ($idade >= 6 && $idade <= 12) {
            functionName($nome, "Infantil", $categorias);
        } else if ($idade >= 13 && $idade <= 18) {
            functionName($nome, "Adolescente", $categorias);
        } else {
            functionName($nome, "Adulto", $categorias);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Olá, Henrique. É legal você querer ajudar o usuário, mas as perguntas do site não podem ser sobre códigos muito específicos. O formato pergunta e resposta é para formar um repositório coletivo de problemas comuns e soluções comuns, então respostas que acabam servindo só para o autor, mesmo que funcionem, tendem a não ser bem vistas. Deixei uns links para o autor da pergunta no campo de comentários acima, sugiro uma lida também, aí pode focar em postagens que atendam ao objetivo do site, tendo um retorno melhor em pontuação e fazendo suas respostas ajudarem um público maior.